# How to define which validation group should be used for a Spring Data Repository action?

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, bean-validation

I have a JPA Spring Data Repository. Can I somehow define the validation groups to be used by Hibernate for a given operation (lets say save)? In some cases I would need to validate some groups, while other cases not. It would be decided on service level. Is it possible with Spring Data?

It would be also ok for me, if I could define validation groups, which are only called for new objects, and not for updates.

Comment: How would you do that with JPA?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli I have no idea. I just know, that if you use Bean Validators, you can define ValidationGroups which should be validated. I thought JPA/Spring Data has such capability as well (since they use bean validation internally)

Comment: In order to validate using validator group you have to use validate method with respective group explicitly.

Comment: The problem ist that JPA cannot do that and Spring Data JPA does not provide things that are not possible by the underlying technology. You have to use beanvalidation in your business logic then you can specify the group

Answer (score -1):

Ooops. Sorry. This solution is for Spring Data Rest.

If you use Spring Data JPA you have to do the validation manually before each JPA call.

------ edited

```
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
protected class RepositoryConfig implements RepositoryRestConfigurer {
  private static final String BEFORE_CREATE = "beforeCreate";
  private static final String BEFORE_SAVE = "beforeSave";

  @Override
  public void configureValidatingRepositoryEventListener(ValidatingRepositoryEventListener validatingListener) {
    validatingListener.addValidator(BEFORE_CREATE, createValidator());
    validatingListener.addValidator(BEFORE_SAVE, saveValidator());
  }
}
```

implement the `createValidator()` and `saveValidator()` beans:

```
public class CreateValidator implements Validator {
  private final LocalValidatorFactoryBean smartValidator;

  @Override
  public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
    smartValidator.validate(target, errors, {whatEverHintsYouWant} );
  }
}
```

Inject service bean into it and calculate the hints there if needed.

You can even create different validators for each entities using the `supports` method.